# Java command line parameters

Tags: java, command-line

I'm just wondering how to do Java command-line with parameters? For example :

> javac Test.java

then

> java Test 3 5

then after running the command line

expected output:

> 3 5

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

      int num1 = 1;
      int num2 = 2;

      System.out.println(num1,num2);


     }
    }
```

Comment: your given code won't compile. You can't send two parameters to `println`.

Comment: just for example too lazy. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use args as input parameters.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(args[0] + " " + args[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix for your code is

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 1) {
            int num1 = args[0];
            int num2 = args[1];
            System.out.println(num1 + "-" + num2);
        }
    }
}
```